# Validar un usuario dentro de la base de datos

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos

Buen dia,

Estoy trabajando como Windows Forms y controles de usuarios dentro de C#, el cual estoy trabajando con una aplicación que actúa como un reloj checador.

Esta primer pantalla actúa, como la pantalla principal. El cual todos los usuarios tiene acceso hasta este momento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro del login, escriben su usuario y al presionar registrar debe de hacer una comparación con los usuarios registrados dentro de la BD.

El codigo que uso es el siguiente:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            
            SqlCommand agregar2 = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select Usuario From Usuarios where Usuario = '"+textBox1.Text+"'", cadena));
            
            if ( textBox1.Text == agregar2.CommandText)
            {
           
            SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand("insert into Registros_ values (@nombre, @Fecha, @Hora)", cadena);
            cadena.Open();

            try
            {
                label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", textBox1.Text);
       
               agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", label2.Text);
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", label1.Text);
                agregar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Correcto");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo insertar" + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
               
                cadena.Close();

            }
        }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No existe en la base de datos o Usuario Incorrecto");
                MessageBox.Show(agregar2.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }
```

Al momento de realizar la consulta me toma todo el valor de la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que solo tome el valor de: DaniLop21, porque al parecer me esta tomando toda la cadena "Select Usuario From Usuarios where Usuario = 'DaniLop21'" y al compararlo obviamente no coindice con el valor del Textbox1 = DaniLop21.

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería mas sencillo utilizar SqlDataReader, podrías utilizarlo de la siguiente manera

```
var reader = agregar2.ExecuteReader(); 
if(reader.HasRows){ //do something }
```

Para mas información sobre el tema puedes consultar la información [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader)

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: ¡Sencillo y practico, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Seria mas sencillo hacerlo con un Linq y un Entity si puedes, en todo caso lo haría mas fácil.

pero en tu caso podrías relizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter agregar2 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Usuario From Usuarios where Usuario = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", cadena);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        agregar2.Fill(ds);
        string usuario= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Usuario"].ToString();

        if ( textBox1.Text == usuario)
        {

        SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand("insert into Registros_ values (@nombre, @Fecha, @Hora)", cadena);
        cadena.Open();

        try
        {
            label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", textBox1.Text);

           agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", label2.Text);
            agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", label1.Text);
            agregar.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Correcto");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo insertar" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            textBox1.Clear();

            cadena.Close();

        }
    }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No existe en la base de datos o Usuario Incorrecto");
            MessageBox.Show(agregar2.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Te falta en si el código para llamar el select de tu base de datos:

```
SqlDataAdapter agregar2 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Usuario From Usuarios where Usuario = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", cadena);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        agregar2.Fill(ds);
        string usuario= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Usuario"].ToString();
```

Editado me falto el punto y coma.